# Transformation in Dataframe Column in pySpark

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a dataframe which looks like below

[image]

Here as you can see in the "Schema" Column there are values like PCP / LCP string, Data Load Supplier string, Cost Type string, Latest Cost CPN,SU,Loc,Med double

This column actually holds the schema of a particular dataset. what i want here is to change all the column values, if there is any space in between or any special character that should be replaced by "_". so in the above example the values will become
PCP_LCP string, Data_Load_Supplier string, Cost_Type string, Latest_Cost_CPN_SU_Loc_Med double

the code i have written is

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf
import re
def process_part(part):
    # Replace slashes with underscores
    processed_part = re.sub(r'/', '_', part)
    # Replace spaces with underscores only if they are between words
    processed_part = re.sub(r'(\b\w+)\s+(/|,)\s+(\w+\b)', r'\1\2\3', processed_part)
    # Replace spaces with underscores between words
    processed_part = re.sub(r'(\b\w+)\s+(\w+\b)', r'\1_\2', processed_part)
    return processed_part

process_part_udf = udf(process_part)
processed_schema_df = schema_df.withColumn('Schema', process_part_udf(col('Schema')))
display(processed_schema_df)
```

with this the output has come as
[image]

can someone rectify the mistake over here

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to achieve your requirement where first you need to make a list of all data types and build a logic around them.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf
import re
def process_part(part):

    '''
    Make a list of data types and Replace ' '<datatypes>,' ' with space<datatype>Commaspace and replace ' '<datatype> with space<datatype>
    '''
    types=["string","double","date"]
    part2=part
    for i in types:
        part2=re.sub(' '+i+','+' ','space'+i+'Comma'+'space',part2)
        part2=re.sub(' '+i,'space'+i,part2)
    
    # Replace slashes with underscores
    processed_part = re.sub(r'/', '_', part2)

    # Replace spaces with underscores between words
    processed_part = re.sub(r' ', r'_', processed_part)

    # Replace , with underscores
    processed_part = re.sub(r',','_',processed_part)

    # Replace extra underscores with one _
    processed_part = re.sub(r'_+','_',processed_part)

    # Replace space with ' '
    processed_part=re.sub('space',' ',processed_part)

    # Replace Comma with ,
    processed_part= re.sub('Comma',',',processed_part)
    return processed_part

process_part_udf = udf(process_part)
processed_schema_df = df.withColumn('Schema', process_part_udf(col('Schema')))
display(processed_schema_df)
```

**Result:**

[image]